# PHP power form not sending all fields to email

Tags: php, forms, email

Im using this php script to send the contents of my form to my email when the user submits the form, but currently im only able to get the last two fields of my form to send in the email.( message and company name are the only two working) How can I get the entire form to send in the email?

```
<form role="form" method='post' action='backend/php_mailer.php'>
<input type="text" name='name' class="form-control" id="yourname" placeholder="Name">
<input type="email" name='email' class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="text" name='phone' class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
<input type="text" name='company' class="form-control" id="company" placeholder="Company Name">
<textarea name='message' class="form-control" id="message" rows="6" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ">SUBMIT</button>
</form>




<?php
if (isset($_POST['email']))

  {

   $userName = $_REQUEST['name'] ; 
   $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ; 
   $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
   $company = $_REQUEST['company'] ;
   $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
   mail("peaceuponelove@gmail.com", $subject,
   $message,$company,$userName );
   echo "Thank you";
   }

  ?>
```

Comment: You are passing $company and $username as additional parameters instead of concatenating them to $message.

Comment: Also use $_POST not $_REQUEST

Answer (score 2):

Each argument of `mail()` has a specific purpose. You cannot just continually pass in arguments and expect them to be appended to the email. You must use string concatenation.

```
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] . '</br>' . $email . '<br/>' . $phone . '<br/> ' . $userName . '<br/> . ' $company;
mail("peaceuponelove@gmail.com", $subject,$message);
```

**Sidenote** You never declared `$subject` in the code that you've shown. So here's a subject:

```
$subject = 'Message from '. $userName .' < ' . $email . ' > ';
```

Comment: Im confused, is the $message the body of the email like $subject, or is it the message the person is leaving in the message section of my form?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i ended up doing to get all fields in email

```
<?php


?>
<form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
<input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
<input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
<input name="phone" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
<textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
</form>
<?php

$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
$message=$_REQUEST['message'].$email.$phone;



    $subject="$name";
    mail("peaceuponelove@gmail.com", $subject, $message);
    echo "Email sent!";

?>
```